# Java Packages/Library Functions

Tags: java, package

I am trying to create a package of library functions for a main Java program but I am have some issues.

I don't know much about about Java packages and I am going through some documentary online.

I have created my directory as such

```
./Program/Program.java
./Program/TestFunc.java
./Program/classes/library/
```

The contents of TestFunc.java are

```
package library;

public class TestFunc {

    public void message01() {
        System.out.println("called message01");
    }

    public void message02() {
        System.out.println("called message02");
    }

}
```

I compiled it as I read in the documentation

```
javac -d ./Program/classes TestFunc.java
```

Which gives me

```
./Program/classes/library/TestFunc.class
```

Then I try to call it in Program.java

```
import library.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting Script");

    }

}
```

When I try to compile using

```
javac -d ./Program/classes Program.java
```

I get the error

```
package library does not exist
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used `-d` which says where to put the *output*, but you haven't told it that the same directory should also be used for *input* on the classpath. Use the `-cp` option for that:

```
javac -d classes -cp classes Program.java
```

(It's not clear whether you're trying to do this from *inside* the `Program` directory, or above it - your source filename appears to be inside the `Program` directory, but you're specifying the output directory as if you were in the directory above...)